# When is space be allocated in databases?

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I came from the developer-side, not the administration.
But here and there I have to choose the datatype when I add a new column in our server (MS SQL or MySQL).

I want to add a column for numbers, so my choice is `int` or `tinyint`. At the moment I choose `tinyint` just because I know I want to store a value between 0 and 100 (a percent value) and it can't be higher.

But is there a difference for the space needed on HDD?
Basically: When is space allocated in databases?

When I create a nullable column for `tinyint` instead of `int` (1 byte instead of 4 bytes), and I insert a row of data with NULL for this column, is there still space allocated? Or just when I enter a number?

When I create a `int` column and just save a 1 into it, is there still 4 bytes allocated?

Answer (score 2):

(This Answer addresses MySQL with ENGINE=InnoDB.)

Your specific question:  Use `TINYINT UNSIGNED` instead of `INT` to save 3 bytes per row (on disk and in cache).  Do it.

Basic guidelines (and TMI):

All numeric types (at least for `NOT NULL`) are fixed length, regardless of the value stored in them:

- `TINYINT` - 1 byte
- `INT` - 4 bytes
- `DOUBLE` - 8 bytes
- `DECIMAL(m,n)` about m/2 bytes.  (The exact number of bytes is complicated.)

`SIGNED` vs. `UNSIGNED` has not impact on space.  Instead, it impacts the range for `*INT` types.  Eg, `TINYINT SIGNED` is -128..127; `TINYINT SIGNED` is 0..255.

`NULL` vs `NOT NULL` -- the space consumed is complex due to `MVCC`, potential for `ROLLBACK`, the storage in BTree structure, etc.  It is *not* worth thinking of `NULL` as a way to save space.  Decide between `NULL` vs `NOT NULL` based on *business logic*, not space.  OK, you could let `0` or `''` be used instead of `NULL`.  But, again, the space difference is so minuscule and complex to compute that it is not worth it. 
 I think that `NULL` vs `NOT NULL` either matters or does not, depending on the `ROW_FORMAT`.

Make the decision between a 4-byte `INT` and a 1-byte `TINYINT` (or other sizes) when you originally create the table; it is costly to change it later.  Be conservative; maybe there are only 10K thingies today, but if the landscape changes, might you exceed the 64K limit of `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` tomorrow?

Most database data can be `UNSIGNED`.

String types (`VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, `BLOB`, etc) are typically variable length, with a 1- or 2-byte length prepended to the space.

`CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL` takes 10 to 40 bytes, plus at least 1 byte overhead.  `VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` (`NULL` or `NOT NULL`) takes 0 to 40 bytes, plus at least 1 byte overhead.  (There may be `ROW_FORMAT` dependencies here, too.)  `TEXT`, `VARBINARY`, and `BLOB` act similar to `VARCHAR`.

Priority #1:  Business logic
Priority #2:  Space

Answer (score 0):

The answer for Microsoft SQL Server is that int always takes 4 bytes and tinyint always takes 1 byte.  If the table contains any nullable columns, one extra bit per row also is used to store whether this column is null, whether it can be or not.  (Unless they changed that behaviour and I forgot about it.)  An added column must be nullable or have a default value to insert when a value isn't given.

varchar(length), for example, is different; one bit and no bytes if it's null, I think, or the actual value length plus two bytes (and one bit) when not null.  So '16' is stored as byte 0 and byte 2 (length 0 x 256 + 2) then character 1 and character 6 - plus the corresponding bit in the map of which columns are null.

I don't know whether MySQL is like this in any way.

In MS SQL I found no particular performance difference between using int or tinyint although of course one uses more disk storage; however, a table row uses about 11 bytes anyway (I think) not counting any data columns or indexes (or nulls).  A modern 32 bit or 64 bit microprocessor will calculate on a tinyint or int value in one stroke, making no difference.  I think I did find that bit columns were slower, but I tried it several versions / years ago.

Our development team has a written policy of using int and not the other types.  I think an organisation contains a natural number of irreversible stupid decisions, so maybe it's just as well to have them be ones that don't matter much.  But I do use tinyint in designs when I think I can get away with it.